# How to let people add a nft(tokeID) of the collectionAddress of their choise to my contract to be able to store it on a mapping?

Tags: solidity

```
//How to let people add a nft(tokeID) of the collectionAddress of their choise to my contract to be able to store it on a mapping?
```

Any ideas, will be very helpfull.

i need to store the tokenID of diferent collection addressess like so :
mapping (address => //tokenID of specific collectionAddress//)

i dont know how to let the contract know which tokeID belongs to any collection Address.

Sorry if i dont express very well my question, thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a nested mapping.

```
mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) public userCollectionToken;

function store(address _user, address _collection, uint256 _tokenId) external {
    userCollectionToken[_user][_collection] = _tokenId;
}
```

---

Or you can store the combination of the collection address and the token ID in a struct, and then pass the struct to a regular mapping.

```
struct NFT {
    address collection;
    uint256 tokenID;
}

mapping (address => NFT) public userNFT;

function store(address _user, address _collection, uint256 _tokenId) external {
    userNFT[_user] = NFT(_collection, _tokenId);
}
```

Comment: Yeah i didnt knew that you can nest a mapping, is cool, and the second option is more easy, but still wont be able to check if that address is in deed the owner of the his nft, maybe a person just add his address with a very expensive NFT that does not own and it will be saved like that in my mapping.

Comment: @julianprdz You can check the NFT owner by calling the NFT collection contract's function `ownerOf()`, passing it the token ID. It returns the owner address that you can validate in your code.